# how to fire local notification on time in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

currently I'm working one project in swift 5. I'm trying to push local notifications on specific date & time. I have tried below code and when I set 60.0 interval then its working find but when I set specific date & time then not working.

I have searched & checked so many question but still didn't found the solution. I have checked below questions

[get current date from [NSDate date] but set the time to 10:00 am](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611632/get-current-date-from-nsdate-date-but-set-the-time-to-1000-am)

[UNUserNotificationCenter Swift - Local Notification Not Firing in specific cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49585160/unusernotificationcenter-swift-local-notification-not-firing-in-specific-cases)

```
      let app = UIApplication.shared


      let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .sound], categories: nil)
      app.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
      let calendar = NSCalendar.current

      let date = NSDateComponents()
      print("before date get ::=> \(date)")
      date.hour = 16
      date.minute = 52
      date.month = 6
      date.day = 20
      date.year = 2019
      date.timeZone = NSTimeZone.system
      print("after custom date get ::=> \(date)")


      let alarm = UILocalNotification()
      alarm.fireDate = calendar.date(from: date as DateComponents)
      alarm.timeZone = NSTimeZone.default
      alarm.alertTitle = "Data success"
      alarm.alertBody = "successfuly"
      alarm.soundName = "Sound.wav"
      app.scheduleLocalNotification(alarm)
      app.scheduleLocalNotification(alarm)

      let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
      content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Elon said:", arguments: nil)
      content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Hello Tom！Get up, let's play with Jerry!", arguments: nil)
      content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
      content.badge = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1 as NSNumber;
      content.categoryIdentifier = "com.elonchan.localNotification"
      // Deliver the notification in 60 seconds.
      let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 60.0 , repeats: false)
      let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: "FiveSecond", content: content, trigger: trigger)
      // Schedule the notification.
      let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
      center.add(request)


  }
```

I expect to set specific date & time to fire local notification.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` not `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` and [UILocalNotificaion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification) is deprecated

```
    let mutable = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    mutable.body = "message"
    mutable.title = "title"

    var date = DateComponents()
    date.hour = 16
    date.minute = 52
    date.month = 6
    date.day = 20
    date.year = 2019

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: date, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "key", content: mutable, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will help you on how to send a local notification every day. You can set an hour and minute.

```
func setUpLocalNotification(_ hour: Int, _ minute: Int) {
    print("Local Notification Setup")

    let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: .gregorian)!;

    var dateFire = Date()

    // if today's date is passed, use tomorrow
    var fireComponents = calendar.components( [NSCalendar.Unit.day, NSCalendar.Unit.month, NSCalendar.Unit.year, NSCalendar.Unit.hour, NSCalendar.Unit.minute], from:dateFire)

    if (fireComponents.hour! > hour
        || (fireComponents.hour == hour && fireComponents.minute! >= minute) ) {

        dateFire = dateFire.addingTimeInterval(86400)  // Use tomorrow's date
        fireComponents = calendar.components( [NSCalendar.Unit.day, NSCalendar.Unit.month, NSCalendar.Unit.year, NSCalendar.Unit.hour, NSCalendar.Unit.minute], from:dateFire);
    }

    /// -> If you want to get tomorrow date you can use this code.
    /*
    dateFire = dateFire.tomorrow!
 */

    // set up the time
    fireComponents.hour = hour
    fireComponents.minute = minute

    // schedule local notification
    dateFire = calendar.date(from: fireComponents)!

    let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.fireDate   = dateFire
    localNotification.alertBody  = "alert body"
    localNotification.alertTitle = "alert title"
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit.day
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification);
}

extension Date {

    var tomorrow: Date? {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: how I can get tomorrow's date?

Comment: dateFire = dateFire.addingTimeInterval(86400) , you can use this code.

Comment: can you update your ans with tomorrow date ? how I can get `86400` value ?